# pygame.rect.colliderect() won't work

Tags: python, pygame

I need to manually check if one image hits another. I can't seem to get a result...
Please this is driving me crazy!!! I have tried for 2 days and it won't work.

I didn't include some of the other code such as Menu().main() but it works well. I can't understand why it won't return true when a zombie is on the player.

```
class Game():

    def setup(self):
        global tiles
        for files in os.listdir(os.curdir):
            if files.endswith(".png") and files != "Player.png" and files != "Zombie.png":
                tilees.append(files)
                numtil = tilees.count(files)
                print("a " + str(numtil))

        fli = pygame.image.load(files).convert_alpha()

        i = 0

        while i <= 1000:
            tiles.append(fli)
            i = i + 1

        global TileLen
        TileLen = tiles.count(fli)

        Game().Game()

    def Game(self):
        global zomx, zomy, zombie, MMS, step, zombieRect
        zombieRect = []
        zomx = []
        zomy = []
        zombie = []
        step = 0
        HP = 15
        Map = pygame.image.load("BG.png").convert()
        Map = pygame.transform.scale(Map, (pygame.display.list_modes()[0]))

        person = pygame.image.load("Player.png").convert()
        person = pygame.transform.scale(person, (30, 30))

        dagger = pygame.image.load("Dagger.png").convert_alpha()
        dagger = pygame.transform.scale(dagger, (13, 13))

        screen.blit(Map, (0, 0))
        perx = 800
        pery = 700

        ai().zombieadd(MMS)

        screen.blit(person, (perx, pery))
        screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5))

        global thething

        thething = 0
        for crap in zombie:

            screen.blit(zombie[thething], (zomx[thething], zomy[thething]))
            print(thething)
            thething = thething + 1

        pygame.display.flip()

        awesome = 1
        fttt = 0
        ff = 0
        ofx = 0
        ofy = 0

        while 1:
            print(perx, pery)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_w:
                        pery = pery - 5
                        if fttt != 1:
                            if awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            elif awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 0)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 0)
                        awesome = 1
                        fttt = 1

                    elif event.key == K_s:
                        pery = pery + 5
                        if fttt != 2:
                            if awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                        awesome = 2
                        fttt = 2

                    elif event.key == K_a:
                        perx = perx - 5
                        if fttt != 3:
                            if awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            elif awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                        awesome = 3
                        fttt = 3

                    elif event.key == K_d:
                        perx = perx + 5
                        if fttt != 4:
                            if awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                        awesome = 4
                        fttt = 4

                    elif event.key == K_e:
                        if awesome == 1:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5+ofx))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        elif awesome == 2:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery+25-ofx))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        if awesome == 3:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5+ofx, pery-5))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        if awesome == 4:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20-ofx, pery+25))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0



            screen.blit(Map, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(person, (perx, pery))
            if awesome == 1:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5))
            elif awesome == 2:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery+25))
            elif awesome == 3:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery-5))
            else:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery+25))

            text = "Health: "+str(HP)
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
            ttex = font.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(ttex, (30, 30))


            thecrap = 0
            while thecrap < thething:
                print(thecrap)
                screen.blit(zombie[thecrap], (zomx[thecrap], zomy[thecrap]))
                if perx >= zomx[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomx[thecrap] = zomx[thecrap] + .09
                        loop = loop + 1

                if pery >= zomy[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomy[thecrap] = zomy[thecrap] + .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if perx <= zomx[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomx[thecrap] = zomx[thecrap] - .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if pery <= zomy[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomy[thecrap] = zomy[thecrap] - .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if person.get_rect().contains(pygame.Rect(zomx[thecrap], zomy[thecrap], 30, 30)):
                    HP = HP - .5
                thecrap = thecrap + 1
            thecrap = 0
            pygame.display.update()

            if HP <= 0:
                print("Game over! Sorry!")
                while 1:
                    abss = font.render("Sorry, but you lost! Press any key to continue...", True, (255, 255, 255))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    screen.blit(abss, (90, 90))

                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        Menu().main()

class ai():

    def zombieadd(self, Num):
        global zomx, zomy, zombie, zombieRect
        zombieRect = []
        zombie = []
        global step

        step = 0
        print(Num)

        while Num > step:
            global zomx, zomy, zombie
            print(step)
            zomx.append(random.randint(0, 600))
            zomy.append(random.randint(0, 600))
            zombieI = pygame.image.load("Zombie.png").convert()
            zombie.append(zombieI)
            zombie[step] = pygame.transform.scale(zombie[step], (30, 30))
            print(zomx[step], zomy[step])
            zombieRect.append(zombie[step].get_rect())

            step = step + 1

        Num = 0

        return 0


Menu().main()

class Game():

    def setup(self):
        global tiles
        for files in os.listdir(os.curdir):
            if files.endswith(".png") and files != "Player.png" and files != "Zombie.png":
                tilees.append(files)
                numtil = tilees.count(files)
                print("a " + str(numtil))

        fli = pygame.image.load(files).convert_alpha()

        i = 0

        while i <= 1000:
            tiles.append(fli)
            i = i + 1

        global TileLen
        TileLen = tiles.count(fli)

        Game().Game()

    def Game(self):
        global zomx, zomy, zombie, MMS, step, zombieRect
        zombieRect = []
        zomx = []
        zomy = []
        zombie = []
        step = 0
        HP = 15
        Map = pygame.image.load("BG.png").convert()
        Map = pygame.transform.scale(Map, (pygame.display.list_modes()[0]))

        person = pygame.image.load("Player.png").convert()
        person = pygame.transform.scale(person, (30, 30))

        dagger = pygame.image.load("Dagger.png").convert_alpha()
        dagger = pygame.transform.scale(dagger, (13, 13))

        screen.blit(Map, (0, 0))
        perx = 800
        pery = 700

        ai().zombieadd(MMS)

        screen.blit(person, (perx, pery))
        screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5))

        global thething

        thething = 0
        for crap in zombie:

            screen.blit(zombie[thething], (zomx[thething], zomy[thething]))
            print(thething)
            thething = thething + 1

        pygame.display.flip()

        awesome = 1
        fttt = 0
        ff = 0
        ofx = 0
        ofy = 0

        while 1:
            print(perx, pery)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_w:
                        pery = pery - 5
                        if fttt != 1:
                            if awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            elif awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 0)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 0)
                        awesome = 1
                        fttt = 1

                    elif event.key == K_s:
                        pery = pery + 5
                        if fttt != 2:
                            if awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                        awesome = 2
                        fttt = 2

                    elif event.key == K_a:
                        perx = perx - 5
                        if fttt != 3:
                            if awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            elif awesome == 4:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 270)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 270)
                        awesome = 3
                        fttt = 3

                    elif event.key == K_d:
                        perx = perx + 5
                        if fttt != 4:
                            if awesome == 2:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 180)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 180)
                            elif awesome == 3:
                                dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                                person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            person = pygame.transform.rotate(person, 90)
                            dagger = pygame.transform.rotate(dagger, 90)
                        awesome = 4
                        fttt = 4

                    elif event.key == K_e:
                        if awesome == 1:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5+ofx))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        elif awesome == 2:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery+25-ofx))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        if awesome == 3:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5+ofx, pery-5))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0
                        if awesome == 4:
                            while ofx >= -6:
                                ofx = ofx - 1
                                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20-ofx, pery+25))
                                pygame.time.delay(1)
                                pygame.display.update()
                            if ofx <= -6:
                                ofx = 0



            screen.blit(Map, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(person, (perx, pery))
            if awesome == 1:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery-5))
            elif awesome == 2:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery+25))
            elif awesome == 3:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx-5, pery-5))
            else:
                screen.blit(dagger, (perx+20, pery+25))

            text = "Health: "+str(HP)
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
            ttex = font.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(ttex, (30, 30))


            thecrap = 0
            while thecrap < thething:
                print(thecrap)
                screen.blit(zombie[thecrap], (zomx[thecrap], zomy[thecrap]))
                if perx >= zomx[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomx[thecrap] = zomx[thecrap] + .09
                        loop = loop + 1

                if pery >= zomy[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomy[thecrap] = zomy[thecrap] + .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if perx <= zomx[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomx[thecrap] = zomx[thecrap] - .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if pery <= zomy[thecrap]:
                    loop = 0
                    while loop <= 5:
                        zomy[thecrap] = zomy[thecrap] - .09
                        loop = loop + 1
                if person.get_rect().contains(zombieRect)):
                    HP = HP - .5
                thecrap = thecrap + 1
            thecrap = 0
            pygame.display.update()

            if HP <= 0:
                print("Game over! Sorry!")
                while 1:
                    abss = font.render("Sorry, but you lost! Press any key to continue...", True, (255, 255, 255))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    screen.blit(abss, (90, 90))

                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        Menu().main()

class ai():

    def zombieadd(self, Num):
        global zomx, zomy, zombie, zombieRect
        zombieRect = []
        zombie = []
        global step

        step = 0
        print(Num)

        while Num > step:
            global zomx, zomy, zombie
            print(step)
            zomx.append(random.randint(0, 600))
            zomy.append(random.randint(0, 600))
            zombieI = pygame.image.load("Zombie.png").convert()
            zombie.append(zombieI)
            zombie[step] = pygame.transform.scale(zombie[step], (30, 30))
            print(zomx[step], zomy[step])
            zombieRect.append(zombie[step].get_rect())

            step = step + 1

        Num = 0

        return 0


Menu().main()
```

Comment: Please I have been at this for so long it would be like Jesus coming down to fix it if someone can help me. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: "I can't seem to get a result". What does that mean? Is the code throwing an error message? Does it simply say they aren't colliding? How do you **know** they're colliding? And do we really need to see all **514** lines of your program? While it is better to post more cod than less code here on SO, there is such a thing as **too much**

Comment: Furthermore, after wading through your code, I don't even see a `colliderect` call anywhere!

Comment: Use one of the `Sprite` collision functions http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: It doesn't say they are colliding and I know they are because I can see it on-screen. I have tried all the different ways of checking collision, including Colliderect.

Answer (score 0):

You're going the long way with a lot of things.

PyGame's Sprite class is optimized for all manner of in-game functionality, and you don't appear to be using it.

However, if you just want to deal with Rects, you have to consider which Rects are being compared. Images are pygame.Surface objects - after a `get_rect` call, you'll get their dimensions but not necessarily their *coordinates*. The Rect you get back from any Surface object's get_rect() call will be with its rect.x and rect.y at (0, 0).

Fortunately -- the get_rect() call allows you to pass in parameters. So, whatever method you are using to track character's x and y coordinates, you can pass those in during the get_rect() call using keywords to get a `pygame.Rect` object that correctly reflects their coordinates.

For example -- and this is *not* based directly on your code, so if this blows up on the first pass, not my fault... :)

```
zombieRect = zombie_image.get_rect(topleft=(zombieX, zombieY))
```

...and then THIS is used to compare against the Player rect, or whatever Rect it is you want to bump it into -- using a similar `get_rect(topleft=(x, y))` technique -- you'll probably start seeing results.

Having said all that I would *strongly* urge you to coalesce things into classes with PyGame objects. Much of PyGame is written in C, and parts of it in FORTRAN and ASM if I recall correctly (please don't hold me to both of those langs, I may be misremembering) so by just placing things under a proper class, you'll make your life a lot easier.